# resize Android canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm a relative beginner with Java and I'm still struggling somewhat with views. I've not had much success with searching through other posts or on-line tutorials. I won't post any code for this because I suspect many of you will know what's going on.

I have a canvas that allows me to draw lines on the screen with my finger, etc. I've got it working fine. My next task is to use a command button to save it as an image. The canvas covers the whole screen so the button I inserted on to the layout (in activity_main.xml) can't be seen.

My specific question is do I deal with the size of the canvas and access to the command button through a method(s) in the DrawView.java class or in the XML file in layout? Links to any good tutorials would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Use FrameLayout to show it overlappingly

In the `XML` the button would come below your `View` whose `Canvas` you are drawing on.

### Frame Layout Example

[image: Android Frame Layout Example]

```
<FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#D6FFD6"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <ImageView
                 android:src="@drawable/android"
                 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
     <TextView
                  android:text="learnandroideasily.blogspot.com"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#003399"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

### Update based on your comments

This does the entire layout dynamically, no button in the XML needed. Replace TextView or ImageView with your button. Change parameters accordingly.

```
public class BlahActivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this);
            rl.addView(cv, GlobalVars.screenWidth, GlobalVars.screenHeight); 
            setContentView(rl);


            ImageView fs = new ImageView(this);
            fs.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            rl.addView(fs);

            TextView fs = new TextView(this);
            fs.setText("Bar seco");
            fs.setTextColor(android.R.color.white);
            fs.setTextSize(1,14);
            fs.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rl.addView(fs);

    }    
}
```

Comment: My canvas doesn't have a view in the layout xml file. The DrawView class is instantiated in the onCreate method of MainActivity. The button is the only object in the xml file at the moment. If you follow me.